# need help with erro code in smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix

```
ParserError: Expected a state variable declaration. If you intended this as a fallback function or a function to handle plain ether transactions, use the "fallback" keyword or the "receive" keyword instead. --> contracts/Mhetoken.sol:88:17: | 88 | function () { | ^
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please include the code in the contract that is causing the error? The message you posted says it's on line 88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the contract code is not provided. But looking at the error message seems like OP is trying to declare a fallback function. The correct syntax is:

```
fallback() external {
      
}
```

`receive` is a new keyword in Solidity 0.6.x that is used as a fallback function that is only able to receive ether.

- `receive() external payable` — for empty calldata (and any value)
- `fallback() external payable` — when no other function matches (not even the receive function). Optionally `payable`.

Comment: CAN YOU SOMEHOW CALL ON CONTACT ME. I EMALILED YOU